# nginx 500 internal server error during email function

Tags: php, nginx

Whenever I tried clicking a button to send email, I see this 500 internal server error at the inspect section in chrome browser. Naturally, no email was sent out. Help!

System is windows server with Apache installed.

Below is the nginx.conf

```
    worker_processes  1;


    events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #staging
    server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        root "html\\staging\\facade\\v1";
        try_files $uri $uri/ /404.html;
    }

    location /admin {
        alias html/staging/admin-fe/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /404.html;
    }

    location /api {

        root html/staging/essence/public;

        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1;
        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-d $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        rewrite /(.*) /index.php/$1; break;
        proxy_pass http://192.0.0.228:19120;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_read_timeout 150;

    }        

    location /crm {

        root html/staging/essence/public;

        rewrite /crm/(.*) /$1;
        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-d $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        rewrite /(.*) /index.php/$1; break;

        proxy_pass http://192.0.0.228:19120;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_read_timeout 150;

       }

    }

    #live
    server {
    listen 8100;
    server_name localhost domain.com www.domain.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        root "html\\live\\facade\\v1";
        try_files $uri $uri/ /404.html;
    }

    location /admin {
        alias html/live/admin-fe/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /404.html;
    }

    location /api {

        root html/live/essence/public;

        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1;
        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-d $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        rewrite /(.*) /index.php/$1; break;
        proxy_pass http://192.0.0.228:19121;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_read_timeout 150;

    }        

    location /crm {

        root html/live/essence/public;

        rewrite /crm/(.*) /$1;
        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-d $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        rewrite /(.*) /index.php/$1; break;

        proxy_pass http://192.0.0.228:19121;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_read_timeout 150;

    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Please reduce that wall of code to a minimal version demonstrating the issue. No one here wants to work through all the code that is irrelevant for the question at hand.

Comment: Also the question lacks the actual code trying to send the message.

Comment: And why on earth do you post an nginx configuration when you claim it is an apache http server?

Comment: Also the entries in the http servers error log file are missing...